# what's the difference between while (this) and while True

Tags: python, sockets, while-loop

Differences between the two implementations, i find it hard learning the difference between the two infinite loop examples, using it in a socket implementation.

```
data = 'dummy'
while len(data): #infinite loop implemented here  
      data = socket.recv(2048)
      print data, ip, port
```

and the second infinite loop implementation..

```
while True: #another example of an infinite loop
   data = socket.recv(2048)
   print data, ip, port
```

Comment: If `len(data) > 0` forever, then there is no difference in operation; in this case, the latter is better, as it is explicitly infinite. If `len(data) == 0` is a possibility, they are not equivalent.

Comment: yea i dont seem to understand the two implementations..i saw it in a code for socket programming

Answer (score 0):

The first loop is not really infinite. `socket.recv` can return empty string, which means the other side closed the connection. In that case, the first loop will stop, while the "true" infinite loop will try to read from closed connection.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the codes are equal because:

```
in : bool(0)
out: False
```

In the first example, if `data` would become an empty list or empty string, then `len(data) = 0` and since `0 -> False` the loop would stop.

The second example is truly an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, `data` is being set inside the loop, so if it is ever set to something with zero length, the loop will exit. It is not necessarily an infinite loop.

In the second case, the loop won't exit (unless something raises an exception).